# TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined: using a command Array in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Making a discord bot might get tagged as duplicate but I can't find anything that fixes this sort of problem.

With this code:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    var args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if(command === 'reactpoll' || command === 'rpoll' || command === 'reactionpoll') {
        if (!args.length) {
            return message.channel.send(`You didn't provide any arguments, ${message.author}! Use &rpoll (title) (Main Body)`);
        } else {

            if(!args[0].includes('(')) {
                message.channel.send('Incorrect Syntax: You need a \'(\'');
            } else {
                for(var e=0; e<args.length; e++) {
                    if(args[e].includes(')')) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                //specifically here 
                if(!args[e].includes(')')) {
                    message.channel.send('Incorrect Syntax: You need a \')\'')
                    .catch();
                } else { 
                e++;
                if(!args[e].includes('{')) {
                    message.channel.send('Incorrect Syntax: You need a \'{\'');
                } else {
                    for(var e; e<args.length; e++) {
                        if(args[e].includes('}')) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    e = args.length - 1;
                    if(!args[e].includes('}')) {
                        message.channel.send('Incorrect Syntax: You need a \'}\'');
                    } else {
                        var bigBoiString = args.join(' ');
                        var e1 = bigBoiString.replace("{", "");
                        var e2 = e1.replace("}", "");
                        var e3 = e2.replace("(", "**");
                        var e4 = e3.replace(")", "**:");
                        message.channel.send(e4);
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I get the error

```
C:\Users\MyName:)\Desktop\HappyDragonBot\bot.js:124
                if(!args[e].includes(')')) {
                            ^
```

I assume that this means that the variable e doesn't have a string assigned to it, but when I console.log(e), it gives me a defined value. Furthermore, lets say I run the command &rpoll (hey hey hey {hey hey hey}, and I simply type in the number 2 instead of e, the code runs just fine. Don't know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that `e` isn't undefined doesn't mean that `args[e]` won't be undefined. The problem is that if this loop:

```
                for(var e=0; e<args.length; e++) {
                    if(args[e].includes(')')) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

finishes without breaking (because no argument includes a `)`), then `e` will equal `args.length`, and so `args[e]` will be undefined.

Comment: Thanks so much! Probably will take this down from Stackoverflow as it's not really a problem more my overlooking a mistake but thank you all the same.